# Unable to Compile class for JSP. Tomcat 7.0.82

Tags: java, json, eclipse, tomcat

I have created a `war` file from a Java web project within Eclipse. It very rightly created a `classes` and `lib` folders in `WEB-INF` directory containing compiled sources and referenced libraries. When I deployed this project on Apache Tomcat 7.0.82, it runs fine for most of the pages except `Main2.jsp` where I get the following exception

> type Exception report
>
> message Unable to compile class for JSP
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP
>     org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:675)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:364)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

The code of `Main.jsp` is below

```
<%@page import="assemble_xml.*"%>
<%@page import="java.io.*"%>
<%@page import="java.util.*"%> 
<%@page import="org.json.JSONObject"%>
<%@page import="org.json.*;"%>
<%
System.out.println("\n*** Inside Main2.jsp");
String data1 = request.getParameter("data");
String sourceApiId = request.getParameter("sourceApiId");
String bpFile = request.getParameter("bpFile");
String context = getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
//data1 = "{000:{name:mkyong.com,messages:[msg 1,msg 2,msg 3],age:100},001:{name:mkyong.com,messages:[msg 1,msg 2,msg 3],age:100}}";
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data1);

System.out.println("\n*** Inside Main2.jsp: jsonObject"  + data1);

Operation op1 = new Operation ("");

HashMap<String, Operation> hm_xml_att  = op1.readOpAttribFromXML2(context+bpFile, jsonObject);
op1.writeXML(hm_xml_att,context + "auth_refine_output" + File.separatorChar + sourceApiId);

//BP bp = new BP(context,context + "\\auth_refine_output\\Mappings.txt",context + "\\auth_refine_output\\" + sourceApiId,context + "\\auth_refine_output\\OFBiz_Process.xml");

//response.setContentType("text/html"); 
//response.getWriter().write("Dataflow file (" +context + "\\auth_refine_output\\OFBiz_Process.xml) generated successfully");  
//System.out.println("\n*** Inside Main2.jsp: Dataflow file (" +context + "\\auth_refine_output\\OFBiz_Process.xml" + ") generated successfully");
%>
```

I am pretty sure that the problem is due to the following two imports

```
<%@page import="org.json.JSONObject"%>
<%@page import="org.json.*;"%>
```

because, when I remove them, the error remains the same but now it's due to not resolving `JsonObject` to a type. Ironically, I have more than three files in `WEB-INF\lib` folder that seem like containing `JsonOject`. Those files are `json-20090211.jar`, `json-20160810.jar` and `json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar`.

All three files are also present in eclipse project but it runs flawlessly in eclipse. I am not the author of this project and not a Java pro anyway. So, I wonder why do we have three files included as dep just for JSON? and why it works fine in eclipse but not from Apache Tomcat 7?

Comment: Hi Muhammad. A couple of posting tips if I may: software items are not themselves code, so they do not need to be code-formatted (Apache Tomcat can just be written in title case, like so). There's no need to state that you appreciate answers, or offer advance thanks or (kind) regards - all of that is assumed, and is trimmed by editors for succinctness. Don't give us more work to do please `:-)`.

Comment: got it man. keep it in mind :)

Answer (score 0):

Semicolon in the last import was the problem. Changing the line from

```
<%@page import="org.json.*;"%>
```

to

```
<%@page import="org.json.*"%>
```

resolved the problem